# Sage TypeError positive characteristics not allowed in symbolic computations

Tags: sage

I am new to sage and have got a code ([link](http://www.weblearn.hs-bremen.de/risse/papers/ICIT11/Goppa_codes_BM.sws) to code) which should run.
I am still getting an error message in the decoding part. The error trace looks like this:

```
in decode(y)
--> sigma[i+1+1] = sigma[i+1]*(z)\
                    -(delta[i+1]/delta[mu+1])*z^(i-mu)*sigma[mu+1]*(z);
in sage.structure.element.Element.__mul__
    if BOTH_ARE_ELEMNT(cl):
-->     return coercion_model.bin_op(left, right, mul)
in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel_cache_maps.bin_op
--> action = self.get_action(xp,yp,op,x,y)

...... some more traces (don't actually know if they are important)

TypeError: positive characteristics not allowed in symbolic computations
```

Does anybody know if there is something wrong in this code snipped? Due to previous errors, I changed the following to get to where I am at the moment:

- `.coeffs()` changed to `.coefficients(sparse=False)` due to a warning message.
- in the code line `sigma[i+1+1] = sigma[i+1](z)\
                     -(delta[i+1]/delta[mu+1])*z^(i-mu)*sigma[mu+1](z);` where the error occurs, i needed to insert `*` eg. `sigma[i+1]*(z)`

I would be grateful for any guess what could be wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are multiplying things not of characteristic zero (like elements related to `Phi.<x> = GF(2^m)`) with elements of symbolic computation like `z` which you have explicitly defined as a symbolic variable

```
Phi.<x> = GF(2^m)
PR = PolynomialRing(Phi,'z')
z = var('z')
```

Basically, the `z` you get from `PR` is not the same one as from `var('z')`.  I recommend naming it something else.  You should be able to access this with `PR.gen()` or maybe `PR(z)`.

I'd be able to be more detailed, but I encourage you next time to paste a fully (non-)working example; trying to slog through a big worksheet is not the easiest thing to track all this down.  Finally, good luck, hope Sage ends up being useful for you!